# Placing image next to multiple line text in header

Tags: fancyhdr

I am trying to recreate the following header created in Word using LaTeX

[image: desired output]

I have attempted to do so by using the fancyhdr package and creating a table as follows

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{ 
\begin{tabular}{l l}
\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{template/header_left}} & {\huge Big text} \\
& Small text \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{template/horizontal}}
\end{tabular}}
```

However, the result looks like this:

[image: Latex output]

these are the two images used to construct the header:

Image 1: [image: horizontak]

Image 2:

[image: left]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `makecell` package often comes handy for these kinds of constructs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{64pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{ 
  \mbox{\makecell[cl]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{header_left}}}
  \makecell[cl]{{\huge Big text} \\[2pt] ~Small text} \\[-9pt]
  {\includegraphics[width=\headwidth]{horizontal}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This uses `\savebox`es and `\parbox`es to construct the header.  Note that fancyhdr is sensitive about `\headheight`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% create header
\sbox1{\parbox[b]{0.5\textwidth}{{\huge Big text}\par Small texty \hrule height0pt}}% move baseline to bottom
\newsavebox{\myheader}
\savebox{\myheader}{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\includegraphics[height={\dimexpr \ht1+\dp1+2pt}]{example-image}%
  \hspace{2pt}\raisebox{2pt}{\box1}% add 2pt gap to left and bottom
  \color{red}\hrule height2pt}}
% use header
\usepackage[headheight=\ht\myheader]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\usebox\myheader}

\begin{document}
The content of my thesis goes here
\end{document}
```

Note that every line (box) has a top, bottom and baseline.  LaTeX tries to space the baselines `\baselineskip` apart, but if two lines run together it instead adds `\lineskip` between the bottom of one and the top of the next.  Tabular is even more complicated.  However, `\hrule` does not obey these rules.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version that is using colored rules instead of your graphics files.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{color}

\makeatletter
\let\old@rule\@rule
\def\@rule[#1]#2#3{\textcolor{rulecolor}{\old@rule[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
\makeatother

\definecolor{rulecolor}{named}{BrickRed}
\setlength{\headheight}{32pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{ 
\rule{2em}{4em}\hspace{2pt}\rule{1em}{4em}\hspace{2pt}\rule{0.25em}{4em} \hspace{3pt}
\raisebox{5mm}[4mm][2mm]{
\begin{tabular}{l}
\huge Big Text \\
\textcolor[rgb]{0.8,0.8,0.8}{Small text}
\end{tabular}
}\vspace{-0.8em}
\rule{1.2\textwidth}{1em} \hspace{3pt}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent \lipsum

\end{document}
```

It will look like this. All lengths can be tailored.

[image: With rules]